# Open Powershell and Change directory in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I want my Windows application built with VB.NET to open powershell onclick of button event and change directory to C:\ and not close window.

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub PowershellToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PowershellToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Process.Start("powershell")
    End Sub
```

I tried to add `"-wait"` after `"powershell.exe"` but that causes an error. Anyone have an idea how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell is a command line executable. It will not attach a console  normally, but if you execute it as the shell, then it should behave as you expect:

```
Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo() With {.UseShellExecute = True, _
                .FileName = "powershell", _
                .WorkingDirectory = "C:\"})
```